# Inherit button functionality in Odoo 10 - Javascript / XML only

Tags: javascript, odoo-10

So, I've created a few buttons in their own modules with their own functionality. They do get displayed on the main POS screen.

I need to change the functionality slightly
- have these button displayed only when a new modal is opened
- the buttons rendered inside the modal will have their initial click functionality

(i do not know any Python)

How do I inherit the buttons functionality in the new modal in order to have the click event do individual tasks according to each button initial definition ?

I tried to use the

```
   click_me: function(){
     button1.click ......
     button2.click
}
```

but for some reason i cant make that happen

Comment: What exactly you want to do and what have you done to achieve your task ?

Answer (score 0):

first of all add your js file following code :

```
odoo.define('Modulename.filename', function (require) {
"use strict";

var form_widget = require('web.form_widgets');
var core = require('web.core');
var _t = core._t;
var QWeb = core.qweb;

form_widget.WidgetButton.include({
    on_click: function() {
         if(this.node.attrs.custom === "click"){
            //code//
         }
         this._super();
    },
});
});
```

after this add your js file in xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <odoo>
        <template id="assets_backend" name="project assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
            <xpath expr="." position="inside">
                         <script type="text/javascript" src="/product_pack/static/src/js/product_pack.js"></script>
            </xpath>
        </template> </odoo>
```

ather that define your click event function in your py file

```
class SalePetOrder(models.Model):
    _inherit = "xyz"

    def java_script(self):
        return {"hello": "world"}
```

after define your function in your xml :

```
<data>
   <header>
    <button name="java_script" string="Java Script" type="object" custom="click"/>
   </header>
</data
```

and yes define your js file and xml file in your manifest /openerp file .

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Hi Manish, thanks for the reply.
I have defined special events inside my modal module and thus have the functionality needed.
I will try your suggestion for future reference and let you know how it went

Comment: I've experimented with ideas and have come to a magic solution :)

Since all the assets are combined into the big magic of Odoo JS file, then all you can do (simple enough) is to created the events for your button and assign an action which is the exact action the original buttons has (looking for the action in the main files is the only tricky part) and this works without going to all the steps.

So - create XML, xpath, js and css files, add specific action to the button on the events method and that's pretty much it. No py, no extra steps